# Add a dynamic header to all outgoing Refit requests

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, middleware, refit

I am using Refit (5.1.67) as my HttpClient wrapper, in a .NET Core 3.1 app using IHttpClientFactory.

The API I am calling is secured using a client credentials token.

I am registering the client with this:

```
services.AddRefitClient<ISomeApiClient>().ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["BaseUrlFromConfig"]));
```

The client has methods that look like this:

```
public interface ISomeApiClient
{
    [Get("/api/somewhere")]
    Task<IEnumerable<MyResponseObject>> GetItems([Header("X-User-Id")] string userId, [Header("Authorization")] string accessToken);

    [Get("/api/somewhere-else")]
    Task<MyResponseObject> GetItem([Header("X-User-Id")] string userId, [Header("Authorization")] string accessToken, int id);
}
```

What I want to avoid is having to explicitly pass accessToken and userId every time I call an endpoint (like above). Ideally, I want to have my client look like this:

```
public interface ISomeApiClient
{
    [Get("/api/somewhere")]
    Task<IEnumerable<MyResponseObject>> GetItems();

    [Get("/api/somewhere")]
    Task<IEnumerable<MyResponseObject>> GetItems(int id);
}
```

It feels like I need some sort of request middleware for outgoing requests, where I can add these two headers. If they were static I would just decorate the whole interface but because these are runtime values that will not work.

I cannot find any help on this one in the docs, and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refit docs now explain how to do this

https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#reducing-header-boilerplate-with-delegatinghandlers-authorization-headers-worked-example

Add a header handler:

```
class AuthHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
 {
    private readonly IAuthTokenStore authTokenStore;

    public AuthHeaderHandler(IAuthTokenStore authTokenStore)
    {
         this.authTokenStore = authTokenStore;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = await authTokenStore.GetToken();

        //potentially refresh token here if it has expired etc.

        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

then register in Startup.cs when registering the client:

```
services.AddTransient<AuthHeaderHandler>();

services.AddRefitClient<ISomeThirdPartyApi>()
        .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.example.com"))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthHeaderHandler>();
```

Comment: Where does IAuthTokenStore  come from? Is it something that you have to define?

Comment: Yes, you can use anything here, its just a place to store your tokens. You could also directly call your auth provider for it, I cache mine as my auth provider has rate limiting

Answer (score 1):

You can use DI to inject your client where do you need it. We use it like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly ISomeApiClient_client;

public ValuesController(ISomeApiClient client)
{
   _client = client;
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
}

[HttpGet("/")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Reply>> Index()
{
  return await _client.GetMessageAsync();
}
}
```